# Pass value while submitting a form button from model to controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am making an application in codeigniter. I am trying to pass value stored in a variable when a submit button is being clicked from model to controller.

How can I achieve this? I have tried the below code so far:

model.php

```
public function loadadd($mekhala_Id) {

      echo  form_open('Payment/amount($count)'); 
      $query = $this->db->get_where('tb_unit', array('mandalam_Id' => $mekhala_Id));
      echo $count= $query->num_rows();
    ?>

 <h1>Members List</h1>
        <table border="1">
            <tr>
                 <th>Unit</th>
                  <th>Unit Secretary</th>
                 <th>Amount paid</th>

            </tr>
            <?php

    foreach ($query->result() as $row)
    {
        //$i=1;
        ?>

            <tr>
                <td> <?php echo $row->unitName ;?></td>
                        <td> <?php echo $row->unit_sec ;?></td>
                       <td> <?php echo form_input(array('name'=>'na','placeholder'=>'Rupees Paid')) ;?></td> 
                       <td><?php echo form_checkbox(array('name'=>'check','value'=>'paid')) ; ?></td>
            </tr>

            <?php
   // $i++;
}
                        // echo $query->result();
                                                                                                     echo form_submit(array('name'=>'sub','value'=>'submit'));
                        echo form_close();
}
           public function loadpayment($paid,$count){




              for($i=1;$i<=$count;$i++)
            {
               $a='na'.$i;
               $paid=array($this->input->post($a));
              $this->db->insert('tb_unit',array('Amount'=> $paid));
          }


          }
          }

?>  
                                      controller.php                                                                                                                                                                  public function amount($count) {

                  $paid=$this->input->post('na');

                   $this->cms_model->loadpayment($paid,$count);
                       }
```

While running this code below is being shown:

> An error was encountered
>
> The URI you submitted has disallowed characters.

Comment: Can anyone help me to resolve this problem.Please

Comment: you should have to read main idea of mvc.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should read again the main idea of the model, view and controller. 
The idea of the models is only to work with the database. You do not use form_open() or other html in models, this should be done in the views.
[This tutorial](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/tutorial/index.html) shows more details.

To pass value with submit you can use hidden field in the form as show [here](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/form_helper.html#form_hidden).

To pass data in a variable when submit button is being clicked: you can set the variable to the value attribute: `echo form_submit(array('name'=>'sub','value'=>"$variable"));`

Comment: I want pass data in a variable when submit button is being clicked.

Comment: How can I acheive this

Comment: Output is not obtained by setting the variable to the value attribute: echo form_submit(array('name'=>'sub','value'=>"$variable")).Please give another solution